# CSS Text Decoration Not Working

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

For some reason my text decoration isn't being set to none.

```
<label style="text-decoration:none;" for="name">Your Name:<br></label>
<input name="name">
```

This is my code. It honestly makes no sense to me why it is not working.

EDIT:
It has bullets on the left of it.

Comment: label doesnt have text decorated in the first place

Comment: and what/how you want to decorate the text

Comment: @awesomestvi It has the bullets.

Comment: ``text-decoration:none`` defines a normal text.

Comment: @AshokShah I want the bullets gone

Comment: @doniyor That's what I have :(

Comment: @Boodog then paste your code with those bullets

Comment: bullets might be coming from list-style of ul. Use list-style: none;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Labels don't generate bullets on their own, unless

- they have `display: list-item` with the appropriate list style, or
- they are contained within `li` elements, which is much more likely the case here.

To remove the bullets you use `list-style-type: none` on the `li` elements containing these labels. List bullets are not text decorations and so are not affected (or indeed, generated) by the `text-decoration` property.

Answer (score 0):

use `list-style-type:none` instead then. here is a small demo

http://jsfiddle.net/3r5RD/